# Solution or plan to solve product measure task

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

So sorry I'm very new to the Theory of Measure and Integration. I failed the task and I don't know how it can be solved.

I've started using Fubini Theorem for the sigma-finite measure, but it is the wrong way. Of course I don't know how it should be

$\int_{[0,1]^{2}}f(x,y)d\mu$ = $\int_{[0,1]} \left ( \int_{[0,1]} f(x,y)d\mu_{Y} \right )d\mu_{X}$

where $f$ is a simple integrated function, and $\mu_{{X}\oplus{Y}}$ is a product Lebesgue' measure

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: BTW, is the parenthese at the third integral's domain correct? $$\int_{[0,1]\color{red})} \ldots$$

Comment: Thanks, updated

Comment: Aleocochodzi, the Community Bot asked. What you quote is the [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem), apparently for a Cartesian square of a real-numbers' unit interval. Are you trying to _prove_ the theorem, or to _apply_ it to solve some problem? In the latter case, please specify the problem itself, rather than a tool you're trying to use. And if you say _'it is the wrong way'_, please describe what way exactly it was, and why / how it appeared wrong.

Comment: As I understand correctly for using this Theorem I need to prove that both measures are $\sigma$-finite. Why I think that's wrong because I got zero points but the task was about 10 points. I'm really so interesting what's wrong.